# How do I get Android to respond to touch drags?

Tags: javascript, android, browser, webkit, touch

I'm creating a web app featuring divs with overflow: scroll styling.  Since the Android browser doesn't support this, I need to use touches and drags with my own custom function.

```
$([element]).
.bind('touchmove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Move elements around as page scrolls, using event.pageY
})
.bind('touchstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Do stuff to set up scrolling event.
}
```

This works fine on iOS devices.  However, in Android, it does not.

With console.log, I found out that event.pageY is always set to zero (in iOS it tells you where your touch is in relation to the rest of the page).  I also get the following cryptic message:

```
W/webview (21798): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

Data on this has been minimal, but it seems to be the case that Android doesn't actually register a touch event until you un-touch.  I don't believe it, since normal pages scroll fine.  I just don't know hot to get it to recognize the real value of pageY, instead of ignoring the Y-value of the touch.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 6):

Please use:

`event.touches[0].pageY`

instead of:

`event.pageY`

it will work.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay on responding.  A co-worker of mine pointed me to the same solution a week ago, when I jumped back into this task, and it worked - thank you very much!

Comment: It would help everyone if you can accept this answer.